# Match tags but not the text between them

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am try to remove some tag from a file.

I want to remove the p tags from the following line

`<p id="id_p111">some text here I want to ignore</p>`

I use

`(\<p id="id_p([0-9]{1,3})">)`

to get the first tag, but for the life of me, cannot figure how to skip the text and select the closing tag so I can delete both of them.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3600709). What about `<p><br></p>`, what should happen to `<br>`?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the code-behind (c#) or in javascript?

Comment: [In my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075437/199263) I assume you want to remove the opening and closing tags, and keep the text between them. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and I don't mean to hijack your question, buy you might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la before you get to deep into your current approach

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: What should happen if you have `<p>1<p>2</p>3</p>`?

Comment: This will clean all _`p`_ tags in html/xml document. `<p(?=[\s/>])(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>|</p\s*>`

Comment: Its really _arrogant_ to set this _`How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?`_ as the answer to  a html parsing question. Unless this is decreed as the only way to do it and we can all go home now ...

Answer (score 1):

- Capture the tag name in one group and the text in another.
- Then use group 1 as backreference in the closing tag.
- Use group 2 (the text) as replacement string.

So:

- `<([^\s]+?).*?>` - matches the tag and saves the tag name in group 1
- `(.*?)` - captures the text in group 2
- `<\/\1>` - matches to closing tag using a backreference to group 1

In JavaScript this looks as follows:

```js
const pattern = /<([^\s]+?).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/gi
const text = '<p>hello</p> <p>world</p>'
console.log(text.replace(pattern, '$2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just remove `p` tag (both start and the closing tag) and not other tags try this :

```
  ("(?i)<p[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: I feel you didn't finish reading the question...

Comment: i didn't get what he mean. but i am trying to figure out what he exactly wants !

Comment: *cannot figure how to skip the text and select teh closing tag so I can delete the both of the*

Comment: he said delete both of the tags...